# Zend Framework 2 InputFilter error when insert and update data

Tags: php, zend-framework2

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Zend\Form\Form::setInputFilter() must implement interface
>   Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pizza\module\Pizza\src\Pizza\Controller\PizzaController.php
>   on line 52 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pizza\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Form\Form.php
>   on line 652

this is the file :

```
 <?php
namespace Pizza\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Pizza\Form\AddPizzaForm;

use Pizza\Form\EditPizzaForm;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Pizza\Model\Pizza;

use Zend\View\Model\JSonModel;


class PizzaController extends AbstractActionController{
    protected $pizzaTable;

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array('pizzas' => $this->getPizzaTable()->find_all()));
    }

    public function addAction()
    {
        $add_form = new AddPizzaForm();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $pizza = new Pizza();
            $add_form->setInputFilter($pizza->getInputFilter());
            $add_form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($add_form->isValid()) {
                $pizza->exchangeArray($add_form->getData());
                $this->getPizzaTable()->save($pizza);
            }

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');
        }

        return array('form' => $add_form);
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);
        if ($id == 0) {
            //redirect to index action Route.
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');

        }else{

            $pizza      = $this->getPizzaTable()->find_by_id($id);
            $edit_form  = new EditPizzaForm();
            $edit_form->bind($pizza);

            $request = $this->getRequest();
            if ($request->isPost()) {
                $edit_form->setInputFilter($pizza->getInputFilter());
                $edit_form->setData($request->getPost());

                if ($edit_form->isValid()) {
                    $this->getPizzaTable()->save($pizza);
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');   
                }
            }

            return array('id'=> $id,'form' => $edit_form);
        }
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
        $this->getPizzaTable()->delete($id);
        $msg = "good";

        $response = new JSonModel(array('response' => $msg));

        return $response;
    }

    public function getPizzaTable()
    {
        if (!$this->pizzaTable) {
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $this->pizzaTable = $sm->get('Pizza\Model\PizzaTable');
        }

        return $this->pizzaTable;
    }
}
```

the Model File : Pizza

```
<?php

namespace Pizza\Model;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;

class Pizza implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $ingredients;
    public $smallprice;
    public $bigprice;
    public $familyprice;
    public $partyprice;

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function exchangeArray($data){

        $this->id           = (!empty($data['id']))          ? $data['id']          : null;
        $this->name         = (!empty($data['name']))        ? $data['name']        : null;
        $this->ingredients  = (!empty($data['ingredients'])) ? $data['ingredients'] : null;
        $this->smallprice   = (!empty($data['smallprice']))  ? $data['smallprice']  : null;
        $this->bigprice     = (!empty($data['bigprice']))    ? $data['bigprice']    : null;
        $this->familyprice  = (!empty($data['familyprice'])) ? $data['familyprice'] : null;
        $this->partyprice   = (!empty($data['partyprice']))  ? $data['partyprice']  : null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy(){

        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputfilter){

        throw new \Exception("not Used");


    }

    public function getInputFilter(){

        if (!$this->inputFilter) {

            $inputfilter = new InputFilter();

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'      => 'name',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 5,
                        'max'       =>30,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'=> 'ingredients',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 5,
                        'max'       =>255,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'      => 'smallprice',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 1,
                        'max'       => 5,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'      => 'bigprice',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 1,
                        'max'       => 5,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'  => 'familyprice',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 1,
                        'max'       => 5,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $inputfilter->add(array(
                'name'=> 'partyprice',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                    array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                    ),
                'validators'=> array(
                    array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'       => 1,
                        'max'       => 5,
                        ))
                    )
                ));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputfilter;

        }else{
            return $this->inputFilter;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: actually there is problem with your Model named `Pizza`, because input filter is defined on Model `Pizza`. So plz check your Model first or plz write the Model so we can sort out your problem. Thanks. and make sure you have added this on your Model also
`namespace Pizza\Model;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class Pizza implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{...`

Comment: i add the code of the Model
can you check it pllz :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `else` in your `getInputFilter` method. I think this is what caused the error. This is why you got the error : `null given`, the `$inputfilter` is never returned the first time.

I corrected it for you. Replace your method by this one :

```
public function getInputFilter(){

    if (!$this->inputFilter) {

        $inputfilter = new InputFilter();

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'      => 'name',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 5,
                    'max'       =>30,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'=> 'ingredients',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 5,
                    'max'       =>255,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'      => 'smallprice',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 1,
                    'max'       => 5,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'      => 'bigprice',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 1,
                    'max'       => 5,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'  => 'familyprice',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 1,
                    'max'       => 5,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $inputfilter->add(array(
            'name'=> 'partyprice',
            'required'  => true,
            'filters'   => array(
                array('name'  => 'StringTrim'),
                array('name'  => 'StripTags')
                ),
            'validators'=> array(
                array('name'   => 'StringLength',
                'options'=> array(
                    'encoding'  => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'       => 1,
                    'max'       => 5,
                    ))
                )
            ));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputfilter;

    }
        return $this->inputFilter;
    

}
```

Comment: when i try it the error go away, but the data not stored in the DB ?

Comment: Test if the condition `if ($add_form->isValid())` returns `true`. Try to `echo 'success';` in the if statement.

Comment: thank you very much man it works finally :D
the problem was in this ligne of code : 

return $this->redirect()->toRoute('pizza');

in the :  function addAction()

Answer (score 0):

You should check that $pizza->getInputFilter() is returning an object that implements a Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface interface. Because setInputFilter() method of your Form class only accepts this kind of objects.

Comment: yes it return : 

$inputfilter = new InputFilter();

....

$this->inputFilter = $inputfilter;

return $this->inputFilter;